# How to only show ID's not already in another table

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to display records from a categories table that don't exist in another table. This works to a certain extent whereby if there are 3 records in the sp_cats table, the display from $stmt2 will show all records except 1 where it should be all except 3. So, it isn't looping through for some reason.

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT `sp_cat_id` FROM `sp_cats` WHERE `sp_id` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $numRows = $result->num_rows;
    if($numRows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

            $spCats = $row['sp_cat_id'];
            echo $spCats . "<br/>";

        }
    }

    $stmt->close();

echo "<br>";

$stmt2 = $link->prepare("SELECT `cat_id`FROM `categories` WHERE `cat_id` != ?");
$stmt2->bind_param("i", $spCats);
$stmt2->execute();
$result2 = $stmt2->get_result();
$numRows2 = $result2->num_rows;
if($numRows2 > 0){
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){

        $cat_id = $row2['cat_id'];
        echo $cat_id . "<br/>";


    }
}
$stmt2->close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this `while()` loop here,

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $spCats = $row['sp_cat_id'];
    ...
}
```

The problem is, in each iteration of `while()` loop you're overwriting `$spCats` value. Besides, you don't have to use two different queries, you can do everything in just one query, like this:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT `cat_id`FROM `categories` WHERE `cat_id` NOT IN (SELECT `sp_cat_id` FROM `sp_cats` WHERE `sp_id` = ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
if($numRows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
        echo $cat_id . "<br/>";
    }
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Rajdeep, you legend! :)

Comment: @Jonathan Glad I could help. Cheers! :-)